# How to read "from first of April to thirtieth of April" in German? (endings for date)

Tags: preposition, declension

How to read "from first of April to thirtieth of April" in German?

Is it "von dem ersten April bis der dreißigsten April"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your suggestion is quite close, there’s only minor errors that make it weird.

You probably would contract *„von dem“* to *„vom“* as well as *„zu dem“* to *„zum“*, and also spell [*„dreißig“*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drei%C3%9Fig) with an sharp S, and you wouldn’t say *„bis der“*. Not only because it isn’t correct, but also because it’s far too cumbersome. You’d simply say:

> ***vom ersten bis zum dreißigsten April***

You certainly won’t hear anyone uttering its non-contracted form:

> *<del>von dem ersten bis zu dem dreißigsten April</del>*

Sometimes it is recommended to set numbers greater than twelve as figures instead of numerals (*„zehn, elf, zwölf, 13, 14“*). You may do so here, or just set all dates in figures, because they’re dates:

> *vom 1. bis zum 30. April*

Comment: Please note that the customary typographic rule that numbers up to and including twelve shall be spelled out is actually _not_ mentioned in the German standard DIN 5008.

Comment: @Loong: Thanks, that mustn’t have been left that way. Like many other details, it’s nowadays merely a suggestion and remains for the author to be decided. At least he or she can’t do too much wrong.

Comment: Note that _zum_ in that kind of phrase is sometimes omitted: _vom 1. bis 30. April_, although that could be considered bad style. If something happens every single day in April, however, it is correct to say _(jeweils) **am** 1. bis 30. April_ (or _täglich vom 1. bis zum 30. April_).

Answer (score 2):

Correct:

> **vom ersten April**

Why using the contraction *vom* instead of *von dem*?

Because *von dem* would mean *from that particular*. If a contracted form exists (like *vom*, *im*, *zur*) you must use it unless you want to emphasize the noun. This is a separate grammar topic.

*[Cannot find an article about this to link, can someone please help?]*

> **bis zum drei*ß*igsten** April (note the ***ß***, not *z* is in your example - it's a common mistake)

Same here, you use the preposition *bis zu*, which goes with Dative, so it gets *bis zum*.

Someone may ask, *why are we using the male form*? Especially English native speakers may have trouble understanding, why we say *vom* and not *von* or *von der*. The answer is simple, we implicitly mean *der Tag*.

Answer (score 0):

*From X to Y*, in respect to date and time, is translated into German as *von X bis (zu) Y*. Examples: "Von April bis Juni", "Von morgens bis abends"

If, as in your case, there's an article, we use contractions: *vom* and *zum* instead of *von dem* and *zu dem*, respectively. So, your phrase is

> Vom 1. April bis zum 30. April

Further examples:

> Vom Januar bis zum April
>   Vom Morgen bis zum Abend

Comment: Actually i am quite certain that for the months, it's ' von Januar bis April ' . so without the definite article.

Comment: @Burki: I second that. In colloquial speech however, it’s occasionally used in that manner.